# python Flask program bump into (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500) after working good for six months

Tags: python, flask

My program using python + flask + pycharm3.1 had been working good for a long time. About 3 days ago, when I run it,  it shows : 
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)**

and the same time, pycharm console shows: 
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1: invalid start byte**

I wrote these lines at head in every file:

```
#coding=utf8
import sys, os
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

I thought it should be some encode error(which was weird because I had maintained this program for about 6 months and it went always great. ), then I add the below just before app.run():

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('gb2312')
```

However, in this way,I can't open some of my html pages while if I use utf8 encoding instead I can open all html pages but can't use js control-widget from outer js file(also 500 internal error)

I just can't get it, why a program can suddenly went wrong, can somebody guide me some thing?
I had tried reinstalled pycharm, reinstalled python, even using eclipse IDE run it and changed a computer to run it, it all shows the same result.

python version: 2.7.6
the pycharm console full errors are as below:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2015 14:30:47] "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 822, in send_static_file
    cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 616, in send_from_directory
    return send_file(filename, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 498, in send_file
    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename or attachment_filename)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 301, in guess_type
    init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 362, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 262, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

and chrome f12 console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) http://127.0.0.1:6378/static/js/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: I don't think pycharm has anything to do with this; are you running the program from within pycharm?

Comment: at first I run it within pycharm, it showed errors above. Then I tried run it from windows cmd, and it showed same errors. Yes, I don't think pycharm has anything to do with it, either. can you come up with anything that matters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the full error message, and the exact version of Python you are using.

Comment: I post messages in the above main question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python issue which is fixed in Python 2.7.9: http://bugs.python.org/issue15207

Comment: Yes, I have solved my problem by uninstalling python2.7.6 and installing 2.7.3. I tried python2.7.9, it worked fine, too.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
I found I was using python 2, then I instead use python3, then the 500 problem disappeared.